# Calling filter functions from within a block-by-block processing function

Tags: python, image-processing, workflow, numpy

I have some memory intensive image filters that I want to call block by block on large images/arrays (because they compute the filter for an entire array, they run out of memory when trying to compute the whole array).

```
def block_process(Ic, blocksize):
    B = numpy.empty(Ic.shape)

    colstart = 0
    while colstart < Ic.shape[1]:
        BlockWidth = blocksize
        if (colstart + blocksize) > Ic.shape[1]:
            BlockWidth = Ic.shape[1] - colstart
        rowstart = 0
        while rowstart < Ic.shape[0]:
            BlockHeight = blocksize
            if (rowstart + blocksize) > Ic.shape[0]:
                BlockHeight = Ic.shape[0] - rowstart

            B[colstart:colstart+BlockWidth, rowstart:rowstart+BlockHeight] = filter1(params) # One of many available filters

            rowstart += BlockHeight
        colstart += BlockWidth
    return B # The complete filtered array
```

My filters are computed in other functions i.e. `def filter1(A, filtsize)`, `def filter2(A, filtsize, otherparam)`, which have an `A` parameter (the input array, given by the block function), and other parameters such as filter size. Some filters have more parameters than others. They return the filtered array.

**Two questions**

1. How do I go about calling one of my filter functions through the block_process function? I don't want to copy the block processing code into each function. In other words, is there a way of specifying which filter to call (and with what parameters) as a parameter of the `block_process()` call?
2. Is there a better way of coding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
def block_process(a, blocksize, filt, args):
    b = numpy.empty(a.shape)
    for row in xrange(0, a.shape[0], blocksize):
        for col in xrange(0, a.shape[1], blocksize):
            b[row:row + blocksize, col:col + blocksize] = (
                filt(a[row:row + blocksize, col:col + blocksize], *args))
    return b
```

There is no need to correct for incomplete blocks at the right and lower edge of the image -- this will happen automatically.  You can simply pass in the filter function and the tuple of arguments.  To call the filter `filter1(a, filtsize)`, use

```
block_process(a, blocksize, filter1, (filtsize,))
```

The code above assumes that the first parameter to a filter is the array to be filtered and that a filter returns a filtered array of the same shape.

It is also possible that your filters can be rewritten in a way that they don't use as much memory, so the blockprocessing would become unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, this is great. My filters are running on large (5000x5000) arrays and require keeping 3-4 additional arrays of the same size in memory, which is why they are running out of memory but that is for another question...

Comment: @Benjamin: often the number of additional arrays needed can be reduced -- this may indeed be for another question :)

Comment: @Benjamin - On a side note, another advantage to doing things in chunks is that it makes easy to spread the calculation across multiple processors using `multiprocessing`.  So, even if the memory problems are fixed later, it can be useful to chunk things like this.

Comment: Simple threading often works as well, since most of the compuationally intensive NumPy stuff runs outside the GIL.

Comment: @Joe Kington: I posted my filter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959171/improving-memory-usage-in-an-array-wide-filter-to-avoid-block-processing if you are interested.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Just came back to this answer... I think you reversed `row` and `col` in the line where you assign filtered values to `b`...

Comment: @Benjamin: You are right.  I probably tested this with a square array, in which case the code actually works correctly.  Looking at my answer again, I realize that it would probably be better to reshape the two-dimensional array to a four-dimensional block array (a two-dimensional array of two-dimensional blocks), since this would make indexing less error-prone.